# Messed up libc 2.17 and libc 2.15 dependency error on 12.04LTS

Tags: dpkg, dependencies

I got myself into a mess in order to solve a libc dependency issue. I downloaded libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb and libc6-dev_2.17-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb from somewhere and then used dpkg to install it. From then on, the nightmare starts. Anyway, here are the relevant output:

```
> cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"


> sudo apt-cache policy libc6 locales
libc6:
  Installed: 2.17-0ubuntu5
  Candidate: 2.17-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 2.17-0ubuntu5 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.15-0ubuntu10.12 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.15-0ubuntu10.11 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.15-0ubuntu10 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
locales:
  Installed: 2.13+git20120306-3
  Candidate: 2.13+git20120306-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.13+git20120306-3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


> sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.17-0ubuntu5) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.12 is installe                                                                             d
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installe                                                                             d
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.11) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.11)
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installe                                                                             d
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by he                                                                             ld packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with trying to install 2.17.

You need to re-install the specific versions of the libraries from 12.04 to fix the issue. Do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.12 libc6-dev=2.15-0ubuntu10.12
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointer. I get another error while doing the first command:`Unpacking replacement libc6 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.12_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libc6/copyright' is different from the same file on the system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.12_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: To resolve the above problem, I manually extracted the deb content and copy those files over. I also tried aptitude. Somehow the problem is solved now although I am not sure how. Aptitude still reports some broken dependency, but the libc6 now is 2.15.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve issue by downgrade libc6

```
$ apt-get install --reinstall libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.15 libc6-dev=2.15-0ubuntu10.15
$ apt-get check
```

If you met the similar error of Bill Z, please try following commands

```
$ mkdir -p /var/backup/usr/share/doc/libc6/
$ mv /usr/share/doc/libc6/* /var/backup/usr/share/doc/libc6/
$ apt-get install --reinstall libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.15 libc6-dev=2.15-0ubuntu10.15
$ apt-get check
$ apt-get -f install
```